# How to efficiently implement Disjoint Set/Union Find data structure?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, data-structures

The data is a list of lists (sets), where all the elements are distinct. There are basically two operations.

- Find the position that contains a certain element. (And fast accessing the set with this position is needed also)
- Union (Join) the two subsets that contain two specified elements.

For example, with a test list: `{{1}, {4,5}, {2}, {3}}`, the `find 5` operation will return index `2` and `union 2 and 5` operation will return `{{1}, {4,5,2}, {3}}`, and the order of the sets and the order of elements in the sets do not matter. More information can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

Current implementations are of OOP style. And when I try to write similar functions, I found that copying the complete list many times seems to be a big problem. Here is a version (very slow for my real problem) demonstrating the operations.

```
unionFind[data_, e_] := 
  FirstPosition[data, _?(MemberQ[#, e] &), {0}, 1, Heads -> False];
unionJoin[data_, {e1_, e2_}] := 
 Module[{e1pos, e2pos}, e1pos = unionFind[data, e1]; 
  e2pos = unionFind[data, e2]; 
  Append[Delete[data, {e1pos, e2pos}], 
   Join @@ Extract[data, {e1pos, e2pos}]]]
```

How to implement the two functionalities with more efficient methods?

Comment: When you `Union`, do you want to just *output* the new list of sets, or do you want to update the data structure to the new value?

Comment: How large are your sets?  How fast (approximately) is fast enough?

Comment: @march update only

Comment: @mikado at a size of one million

Comment: I think making an `Association` where the `Key`s are the entries and the `Values` are the positions would work nicely.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `HoldFirst` to address copying the large list.

```
ClearAll[findJoin];
Attributes[findJoin] = {HoldFirst};
findJoin[list_, v_] :=
 Module[{vPos, fPos},
  vPos = First@FirstPosition[list, v];
  fPos = First@FirstPosition[list, vPos];
  If[vPos != fPos,
   list[[vPos]] = Join @@ list[[{vPos, fPos}]];
   list[[fPos]] = Nothing;
   list = list; (*Activate the Nothing*)
   ];
  ]
```

Then

```
u = {{1}, {4, 5}, {2}, {3}};
findJoin[u, 5];

u

(* {{1}, {4, 5, 2}, {3}} *)
```

I'm not certain how the `list = list` bit to activate the `Nothing` will affect the memory.  I don't think there is a function to shrink a list of list by effectively deallocating a row and updating the *next* pointer of the prior row to the row following the deallocated row.  I think that maybe too low level for *Wolfram Language* directly.  Though I believe you can write a [Symbolic C](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/SymbolicC/tutorial/Overview.html) function in *Mathematica* and compile it for this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach where I use two associations. One uses elements as keys, and set index as the value, and the other uses set index as a key, and set members as the value. This way both set index extraction, and set member extraction are order 1 operations. The union operation will be slower, as it will depend on the sizes of the sets. These associations will be encapsulated in a `DisjointSetObject`, and the function `DisjointSet` will create the container. First, the definition of `DisjointSet`:

```
DisjointSet[set_] := With[{vars = {Unique["Index"], Unique["Set"]}},
    vars = {
        Association @ Map[Thread] @ Thread[set -> Range @ Length @ set],
        AssociationThread[Range @ Length @ set, set]
    };
    DisjointSetObject[vars, Sequence @@ vars]
]
```

`DisjointSet` will create a `DisjointSetObject` container from a disjoint list of sets. For example:

```
ds = DisjointSet[{{1,9,2}, {3, 22, 4}}]
```

> DisjointSetObject[{Index43, Set44}, <|1 -> 1, 9 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 22 -> 2,
>      4 -> 2|>, <|1 -> {1, 9, 2}, 2 -> {3, 22, 4}|>]

The association `Index43` returns the set index associated with a set element, while `Set44` returns the members of a given set index. For example:

```
Index43[9]
Set44[2]
```

> 1
>
> {3, 22, 4}

Let's add some formatting so that we don't have to see the guts of the `DisjointSetObject`:

```
SetAttributes[DisjointSetObject, HoldFirst]

MakeBoxes[obj:DisjointSetObject[{index_, sets_}, __], StandardForm] ^:= With[
    {
    above = {
        {BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Elements: ", Length[index]}]},
        {BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Sets: ", Length[sets]}]}}
    },

    BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[
        DisjointSetObject,
        obj,
        None,
        above,
        {},
        StandardForm,
        "Interpretable"->Automatic
    ]
]
```

We also need to add accessor functions extract the needed information from a `DisjointSetObject`:

```
DisjointSetObject[{index_, sets_},__]["Index", i_]:=Lookup[i] @ index
DisjointSetObject[{index_, sets_},__]["Index"]:=Values[index]
DisjointSetObject[{index_, sets_},__]["Set",i_]:=Lookup[i] @ sets
DisjointSetObject[{index_, sets_},__]["Set"] := Values[sets]
```

Examples:

```
ds["Index", 1]
ds["Index"]
ds["Set", 2]
ds["Set"]
```

> 1
>
> {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2}
>
> {3, 22, 4}
>
> {{1, 9, 2}, {3, 22, 4}}

Finally, here is a union function for joining sets:

```
union[a_,b_][DisjointSetObject[{index_,sets_}, __]] := Module[{min, max},
    {min, max} = Sort @ Lookup[{a,b}] @ index;
    If[min =!= max,
        AssociateTo[index, Thread[sets[max] -> min]];
        sets[min] = Join[sets[min], sets[max]];
        KeyDropFrom[sets, max];
        sets[min],

        Null
    ]
]
```

Example:

```
union[9,3][ds]
```

> {1, 9, 2, 3, 22, 4}

```
ds["Set"]
ds["Index", 1]
```

> {{1, 9, 2, 3, 22, 4}}
>
> 1

Here is an example of a much larger disjoint set:

```
SeedRandom[1]
ds = DisjointSet @ First @ RandomPermutation[10^5]
```

> DisjointSetObject[Elements: 100000
>   Sets: 16
>   Data not in notebook; Store now »
>   ]

Some timings:

```
Length @ ds["Index"] //AbsoluteTiming
Length /@ ds["Set"] //AbsoluteTiming
ds["Index", 100] //AbsoluteTiming
ds["Set", 12] //AbsoluteTiming

Length @ union[100, 2000][ds] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.01876, 100000}
>
> {0.000018, {9743, 30337, 46380, 6309, 3770, 2832, 190, 21, 50, 195, 50, 57, 
>     40, 15, 6, 5}}
>
> {5.*10^-6, 3}
>
> {4.*10^-6, {1896, 42668, 64491, 17865, 25054, 92934, 26782, 16270, 93890, 
>     78509, 22904, 22143, 79565, 89543, 88522, 36050, 45929, 37141, 77845, 68168,
>      42935, 61483, 25101, 49390, 34633, 75935, 4324, 27176, 56173, 61185, 56621,
>      13551, 36160, 95703, 64402, 39427, 72330, 11235, 79608, 64703, 51041, 
>     83940, 76202, 62819, 47313, 73564, 70721, 50365, 65714, 82230, 90602, 74114,
>      43462, 67170, 58859, 13864, 13623}}
>
> {0.046046, 76717}